# How do you find terminal key codes for bash on mac to use with keyboard bindings?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2

I want to be able to create a key binding for use in iTerm2, but I don't know how to find the key codes to create the binding I want. I want to create a binding of `option` + `command` + `t` that will open another terminal tab in the same directory.

There are some programs for Linux that do this and some for MacOS as well, but none of the ones I have found work for the keys I'm interested in. I've tried `control` + `v`, followed by the key to be identified, which works for some keys (`esc` and `delete`), but not for `option` and `command`. I've also tried `sed` followed by the key, with the same results. Below is a key binding that works when you press `tab`.

How can I easily find the terminal key codes I'm looking for?

```
bind '"\t":"open . -a iterm \x0a"'
```

Comment: There are no such terminal key codes, because neither "option" nor "command" are something the (inside of the) terminal knows anything about.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Is the only way to create a key mapping with those keys with iTerm2 preferences, or is there another way?